# Obtener los resultados de todos los partidos en los que se han enfrentado dos equipos

Tags: mysql

Es mi primer día aprendiendo SQL y me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para obtener los resultados que se han obtenido entre dos equipos de la liga.

Necesito seleccionar, por ejemplo, los partidos entre Barcelona y Real Madrid.

Mi tabla es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado Alaves y Eibar por poner cualquiera

Answer (score 1):

Si quisieras únicamente seleccionar las filas que representan los partidos que se han jugado entre el "Barcelona" como hometeam y "Real Madrid" como awayteam, la consulta SQL debe ser la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sp1
WHERE (hometeam="Barcelona" AND awayteam="Real Madrid") OR
      (hometeam="Real Madrid" AND awayteam="Barcelona");
```

- Referencia: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: Hola Jonrodsanz, en efecto, si hago esto me sale bien! pero necesito ambos enfrentamientos, no solo uno.

Comment: Gracias BetaM. @Roberto, he actualizado mi respuesta en base a tu especificación.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Si esta respuesta  ha resuelto su problema, agradecería si pudiera marcarla como correcta, a su servicio, saludos.